# Python package not being found on Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have the following project structure:

```
foo
│
├── foo
│   ├── cli
│   │    ├── tests
│   │    └── __init__.py
│   ├── core
│   │    ├── tests
│   │    └── __init__.py
│   ├── tests
│   │    ├── __init__.py
│   │    └── test_foo.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── foo.py
├── kube
├── requirements
├── ...any-other-non-source-related
└── README.md
```

Inside the `foo/foo.py` file I have the following placeholder code:

```py
import cli
import core


def say_hi():
    print('hi')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    say_hi()
```

And on the file `foo/tests/test_foo.py` I have the following:

```py
from foo import foo


def test_foo():
    foo.say_hi()

    assert False
```

Then, in shell, I'm getting the following:

```
$ python foo/foo.py 
hi
$ pipenv run pytest
===================== test session starts =====================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/python-project-folder-structures
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                         

===================== ERRORS =====================
_____ ERROR collecting foo/tests/test_foo.py _____
ImportError while importing test module '/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/python-project-folder-structures/foo/tests/test_foo.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
foo/tests/test_foo.py:1: in <module>
    from foo import foo
foo/foo.py:1: in <module>
    import cli
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cli'
!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!
===================== 1 error in 0.05s =====================
```

Can anyone helps? Why Pytest is not founding my imports? I've tried a bunch of approachs, even with `tests` folder outside the `foo` folder (on root level) but the error still persists.

The only way that I've found to fix that is putting a `conftest.py` file on the code level, with that it would be discovered by `pytest`. I really don't want to do that, since I want to decouple my testing from my source code.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone strugles with this, I was able to find a solution. I removed the `__init__.py`  file from the `foo` directoty, giving this structure:

```
foo
│
├── foo
│   ├── cli
│   │    ├── tests
│   │    └── __init__.py
│   ├── core
│   │    ├── tests
│   │    └── __init__.py
│   ├── tests
│   │    ├── __init__.py
│   │    └── test_foo.py
│   └── foo.py
├── kube
├── requirements
├── ...any-other-non-source-related
└── README.md
```

Them, on mt test, I got the following now:

```py
import foo


def test_foo():
    foo.say_hi()

    assert False
```

I noticed that the behaviour of Pytest is to go from the test until the root dir, identifying packages. Since `foo` was a package (with a `__init__.py` file) it was adding it as one on my `PATH` :)

**IMPORTANT**
Notice that the `import foo` statement is regarding the `foo.py` file, not the `foo` directory. So, if your file is called `boo.py` inside the `foo` directory, the import should be: `import boo`